# Confusion about ItemPage in Hub template for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, pivot

I'm kind of new to the Hub concept in the new Windows Phone 8.1 environment. Although it doesn't sound strange to me.

The standard template has three page types:

1. HubPage.xaml
2. SectionPage.xaml
3. ItemPage.xaml

I've managed to fill the hub and section pages quite easily, but I'm wondering, if I select an item in a section (or hub page), how should I design a page for the item I selected?
The items don't hold information about what the page should look like.

Should I create grids or stackpanels for each item and make them visible programmatically?

If I'm not being clear, please ask to elaborate.

Comment: The Hub template is already used in a few Windows 8.1 Bing apps, you should look at those for examples of how the Hub template can be used.

Comment: @NeilTurner I guess I'm not really into Bing... I'll most certainly check that out! Thanks